# how to force a graphical password prompt box for git gui?

Tags: git, passwords

I tried this:
`git config --global core.askpass /usr/lib/git-core/git-gui--askpass`
(I found `git-gui--askpass` using `locate git-gui--askpass`)

but git gui (when pushing) still asks the password at the terminal text prompt.

it only happens for one project, the other projects show the graphical prompt. I compared the .git/config from both and also the ~/.gitconfig and saw no clue on what is causing that problem, that is quite confusing... May be I should do some more detailed throughout configuration to grant it will always work I guess?

I need it because I always forget that the pw may be asked on the terminal and keep waiting it show on the dialog box for a long time :(

this weird trick to force it to be shown:
`xterm -e "(nohup git gui&disown)&disown;sleep 3"`
has the side effect of breaking credential cache that seems to require a socket to work:
`git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=1800'`
so I have to type again the pw even after one minute :(

project OK .git/config (least some sections)

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://user@somewhere
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = true
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
[gui]
  wmstate = normal
  geometry = 1920x1026+0+24 533 333
```

Project Annoying .git/config (less some sections)

```
[credential]
  helper = cache --timeout=1800
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://user@somewhere
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = true
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
[gui]
  wmstate = normal
  geometry = 1364x683+-10+14 513 397
```

~/.gitconfig (less some sections)

```
[credential]
  helper = cache --timeout=1800

[giggle]
  main-window-maximized = false
  main-window-geometry = 999x698+7+25
  main-window-view = HistoryView
  show-graph = true
  history-view-vpane-position = 238
  file-view-vpane-position = 631

[merge]
  tool = meld

[diff]
  tool = meld

[core]
  excludesfile = ~/.gitignore_global
  askpass = /usr/lib/git-core/git-gui--askpass
```

PS.: I am using linux

Comment: wait... git-gui--askpass doesnt appear to mean "graphical password prompt" in any way right? I just tested the other project and even with that global set it works while this one wont :(

Comment: `git-gui--askpass` definitely means "graphical password prompt" — the program is written in Tcl/Tk and shows a simple graphical dialog.

Comment: It could be the password is not requested by `git` but by `ssh` or `ssh-agent`.

Comment: @phd mmm... the URL of the working one starts with `https`, the failing is `ssh`! could be that?!

Comment: It seems so. Try setting environment variable `export SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/git-core/git-gui--askpass` so that ssh also uses the program.

Comment: didn't work, but looks like a great tip, some env var may be the solution!